# Interpreting fitted values returned by HoltWinters

Tags: holtwinters

I'm running holtwinters to return a fitted model on my data, and need help interpretting what the fitted object is returning. Here is what I'm getting:

[holtwinters_fitted_object_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUC6Q.png)

My interpretation is:
1) Level - indicates a running mean of the at that point
2) Trend - indicates the weight of the "trend" as an influence on that data point
3) Season - indicates the weight of the "seasonality" as an influence on that data point
4) I dont know what xhat is supposed to indicate? 
Can you please validate my understanding of 1,2,3 and explain what #4 is?
Thanks!